# Does aborting a mission in Ingress cause loss of progress?

Tags: ingress

When aborting a mission in Ingress will I loose the current progress and have to start over from the beginning or is Ingress kind enough to allow me to pick the mission up without having to revisit the completed waypoints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, aborting a mission will delete your progress.

> [Be wary: should you choose to abort a Mission before it’s complete, your progress will be lost and you will be required to start over from the beginning of the Mission.](https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/6099278?hl=en&ref_topic=3403241)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It has quite a bit of useful information about missions.